# Extracting specific information (position) from OldValue using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the old position value of a div element on a page using the Mutation Observer. This is the code that I have:

```
       var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);
       var target = document.getElementById('test');

       var config = {
       attributes : true,
       childList : false,
       subtree : false,
       attributeOldValue : true,
       };

 mutationObserver.observe(target, config)

function test (){
  var target = document.getElementById('test');
  target.style.backgroundColor  = "black"
 }

  function callback(mutations, mutationObs){

   for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length ; i++){

    var mutation = mutations [i];
    alert(mutation.oldValue)

 }
 }
```

When the color of my test div changes, I get an alert with all the old style attribute value.

Alert : "position: relative; top:40px;"

Is there a way to only use the top value for example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split you string and get what you need.

```
var alertValueSplit = mutation.oldValue.split("top:")
var topValue = alertValueSplit[1]
```

Comment: Awesome I was thinking about doing something like that but I was wondering if there was something more direct. But thank you for your answer!